# Datepicker onchange issue with window.location parameter is repeated in MVC4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, datepicker

I have a problem when I choose a date of the DatePicker everything seems all right:

```
    $("#datepicker").change(function (ev) {
        var selectedDate = $("#datepicker").val();
        var month = fechaSeleccionada.toString().substring(0, 2);
        var day = fechaSeleccionada.toString().substring(3, 5);
        var year = fechaSeleccionada.toString().substring(6, 10);
        var date = month + day + year;

        var link = '@Url.Action("ListConcreteDay", "Detail",new { id = ViewBag.Id } )' + '/' + date;
    }
```

the result of link after selecting a date for the first time is correct, something like

```
/Detail/ListConcreteDay/C50000/11122013
```

But when I choose again, the date variable is appended again and it looks like this

```
/Detail/ListConcreteDay/C50000/11122013/03042013
```

and this is not correct. How can I fix this?

Im doing this this way because I think its imposible to asign a javascript variable to the `@Url.Action` Method. Am I right?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can combine url.action with the javascript

```
var link = '@Url.Action("ListConcreteDay", "Detail",new { id = ViewBag.Id, date = "----" } )'.replace("----", date);
```